# change outliers to NAs while keeping existing NAs

Tags: r

I am new to r. I have a dataframe showing `8 trials` per participant (in rows) per 4 different tasks/measures (in columns). I would like to `remove outliers*` (per participant per task) and convert them to NAs while keeping pre-existing NAs.

The code I am using is below; it is throwing out the pre-existing NAs (i.e.,the NAs that exist within the raw dataframe) with the additional result that I cannot get a dataframe back (it won't accept as.data.frame) I think because of unequal sizes.  I presume the problem is the remove outliers function but

1. I thought that when the action on the NAs was within a function it was just stating how to deal with NAs during the function application only, and
2. I have tried to change the function with variations on na.rm = FALSE throughout but that won’t run.  Any help much appreciated.

> fname = "VSA perceptual controls_right.csv"
>   ctrl_vsa_trials = read.csv(fname, header = TRUE, stringsAsFactors = FALSE, na.strings = c(""))

```
remove_outliers = function(x, na.rm = TRUE, ...){
  qnt = quantile(x, probs = c(.25, .75), na.rm = na.rm, ...)
  H = 1.5 * IQR(x, na.rm = na.rm)
  y = x
  y[x < (qnt[1] - H)] = NA
  y[x > (qnt[2] + H)] = NA
  y
}

ctrl_vsa_trials_clean = aggregate(cbind(Pre_first,Post_first,Pre_adj,Post_adj) ~ Ppt, ctrl_vsa_trials, remove_outliers, na.action = NULL)
```

- this is due to issues I had with the measuring device, I feel it is justified!

Comment: What do you mean by "throwing out existing NAs?

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure that I understand what you exactly need, but if what you are trying is to replace columns with cleaned columns, you can try this:

```
ctrl_vsa_trials_clean <- ctrl_vsa_trials
cols <- c("Pre_first", "Post_first", "Pre_adj", "Post_adj")
ctrl_vsa_trials_clean[, cols] <- apply(ctrl_vsa_trials_clean[, cols], 2, 
                                       remove_outliers)
```

Comment: On closer inspection this is not what I need. As far as I can figure out the proposed solution removes outlier observations per task. However, I would like to remove outliers that are calculated per participant per task.

Comment: You are going to have to think about the proper shape for your data set, is it one row per participant*task with 8 task measures or is it one row per participants or do you want to transpose.